# How to change a set to list of different types in java?

Tags: java, list, set

Now how to store that values of set in a list. Here  the set and list is of different type(ProductAttribute and PersistableProductAttribute).

```
for(ProductRelationship productrelationship:productRelationshipList)
{
    Product product=productrelationship.getRelatedProduct();
    PersistableProduct ppTem=new PersistableProduct();

    Set<ProductAttribute> aSet = product.getAttributes();
    List<PersistableProductAttribute> aList = new ArrayList<PersistableProductAttribute>();
// I need to store here in a list.
}
```

Comment: This can be done only if ProductAttribute extends PersistableProductAttribute. If it is the opposite (which makes more sense to me), you should check the instance of the ProductAttribute, and if it is Persistable, cast it to Persistable and add it to list.

Comment: I am afraid, that your question is still a bit vague. In general, if you want to store different classes in the same list you chose a common type of the objects for the list. For example `List<Object>` would work, since all classes derive from `Object`. In your case I am wondering if `PersistableProductAttribute` could be an extension of `ProductAttribute` ? In which case your list should be `List<ProductAttribute>`

Comment: or of course you could cast as George Zougianos suggested. Though you should be sure that you don't loose important information when casting from `ProductAttribute` to `PersistableProductAttribute`

Answer (score 0):

Its just a simple one I have got it after trying several times by myself.First I need to create a set for PersistableProductAttribute and I have to get the attributes of it using loop and I need to copy that set to list. Now it works fine because the set and list are same type. So we can copy a set to list using add() method in java.

```
 Set<PersistableProductAttribute> ppaSet = new 
 PersistableProductAttribute<>();
 for(ProductAttribute x:aSet)
 {
  // Get all the attributes here using get() 
  //and set() methods
  // Copy the set to list as follows,
    aList.add(ppaSet);
  }
```